# Sending alert using multiple metric with Prometheus alert manager

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am evaluating Prometheus for a certain business case. I have been following the documentation but I wasn't able to find a example depicting my requirement.

Below is my business case.

I will pump data (PULL) to Prometheus with the following metrics on one PULL cycle. Of course in one PULL cycle I could also pump another set of exact same metrics, but the asset-id's are going to be different.

```
test_value_one{asset_id="123"} 0.215
test_value_two{asset_id="123"} 0.815
test_value_six{asset_id="123"} 0.715
```

My question is

Can I build a single rule using multiple metrics (same asset-id). I think it is possible to use multiple metrics with the expressions (expr). But my requirement is as below.

```
name: iot_rules
  rules:
  - alert: threshhold_alert
    expr: test_value >= 4
    #for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: critical     
      Additional text : The other metric values are 0.815 and 0.715
    annotations:      
      summary: 'Error detected on {{$labels.assset_id}}'
```

If you look at the additional text in the alert rule, the values **0.815** and **0.715** need to come from the other two metrics viz *test_value_two* and *test_value_six* respectively. Is this something I can achieve since my goal is to provide a comprehensive view of the other metrics as well in the single alert that I intend to send.

Comment: Found a way to achieve this?

Comment: @ThatChrisGuy : Well not the way I wanted, but there is a workaround on the alert-manager configuration to aggregate data.
The 'alert-manager.yml' will aggregate data based on asset-id. I basically then aggregate the data based on asset-id and send it on the 'promwebhook' from where I then construct the text I require. I obviously have to expose an 'promwebhook' endpoint. Good luck. The documentation is a struggle, though the product is great. I have answered my question for you reference,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below configuration on my alert-manager.yml, helped aggregate data based on asset-id. Note the "group_by" tag below. I exposed a RESTAPI for the promwebhook from where I construct the text required.

```
global:

route:
  group_by: ['asset_id']
  group_wait: 5s
  group_interval: 5s
  repeat_interval: 2m
  receiver: node
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
expr: test_value_one - test_value_two >= 4  or test_value_two - test_value_six >= 4
```

or similar